# How to delimit string in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string like below:

```
"[Larry C-Loan Officer]:Comment entered in Portal logged in as LO"
```

I want to separate this string like:

```
1) Larry C-Loan Officer 
2) Comment entered in Portal logged in as LO.
```

How to do that in SQL?

Comment: Don't store such things in a database to begin with. Something that would be easy to do with a regular expression in C# or Java is *very* difficult to do in SQL. SQL is a query language. It's *very* weak in string manipulation, especially T-SQL. Storing multiple values like this breaks the most fundamental design rule. Use properly designed tables and different fields for different pieces of information.

Comment: Just use [string functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** store such things in a database to begin with. Storing multiple values like this breaks the most fundamental design rule. Use properly designed tables and different fields for different pieces of information.

Besides, SQL is a query language. It's very weak in string manipulation, especially T-SQL. Something that would be easy to do with a regular expression or a multi-character separator in C# or Java is very difficult to do in SQL.

The text has two parts, one of the surrounded by quotes and the rest separated from the first one with `:`. It's not enough to split it in two. In C# or Java you could split on `]:` and trim the first `[` character, although that would be slower than a regular expression that extracted the parts. The regular expression `\[(?<person>.*?\]:(?<comment>.*)` will parse this string and extract two named parts, `person` and `comment`.

T-SQL though has no regular expressions and no multi-character split.

- The best you could do is store the data in two separate fields
- If that's not possible, parse the string on the client.
- As a last resort, split on `:` and hope there are no colons in either part, then trim the quotes:

```
declare @text varchar(200)='[Larry C-Loan Officer]:Comment entered in Portal logged in as LO';

select REPLACE(REPLACE(value,'[',''),']','')
from string_split(@text,':');
```